# References about non uniqueness of solution in ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am looking for some example of IVP with non unique solution. I already know the examples of $f(x,y)=k\sqrt{y}$ and $f(x,y)=k y^{2/3}$. Any book or link is welcome.

Comment: Some more examples: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239284/can-a-differential-equation-have-non-unique-solutions, Uniqueness and Nonuniqueness Criteria for Ordinary Differential Equations
 By Ratan Prakash Agarwal, Ravi P. Agarwal, V. Lakshmikantham, and search the web for notes with more examples. Regards

Comment: @PostNoBills: Added as requested. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:

- Uniqueness and Nonuniqueness Criteria for Ordinary Differential Equations By Ratan Prakash Agarwal, Ravi P. Agarwal, V. Lakshmikantham
- Some more examples: [Can a differential equation have non unique solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239284/can-a-differential-equation-have-non-unique-solutions)
- Search the web for notes with more examples.

Comment: Great references, and a fine link, too! +1